How to define type file for nested objects in Nest.js & GraphQL?
I'll give you an example of json data to make you understand better:
example data:
{
  id: "123",
  categories: ["456"],
  details: {
    detail1: "123",
    detail2: "456"
  }
}

how do i need to code the type file for this data?
this is what i did:
data.type.ts file:
@ObjectType("DataType")
export class DataType {
  @Field(type => ID)
  id: string
  @Field(() => [String])
  categories: string[]
  @Field(() => DetailsType)
  details: DetailsType
}

details.type.ts file:
@ObjectType("DetailsType")
export class DetailsType {
  @Field(() => String)
  detail1: string
  @Field(() => String)
  detail2: string
}

I think it should work but I'm getting this error:
Cannot determine a GraphQL output type for the 'details'. Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator.

I solved the problem!
I forgot to add @ to ObjectType in details.type.ts file. When I added the @, problem solved and everything is working fine.
